# Why after changing a static readonly field via reflection the output of that readonly field is old?

Tags: c#, .net, jit, system.reflection, inlining

Why is the "someValue" variable which is readonly (but we still can change its value via reflection) output as "10", although it actually did change to 55?

```
static class Program
{
    static readonly int someValue = 10;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(someValue); // 10

        typeof(Program)
             .GetField("someValue", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
             .SetValue(null, 55); // change readonly field via reflection to 55

        Console.WriteLine(someValue); // output in console 10, 
                                      // but in visual studio debugger it shows 55

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: "but in visual studio it shows 55" Can you describe where you saw 55? In the debugger?

Comment: yeah, i just moved my mouse onto the someValue and it showed me 55 before executing the second Console.WriteLine

Comment: I successfully reproduced this. Wow this is freaky.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce this as well. For some reason, when `someValue` is not marked as `static` both the debugger and console shows `55`

Comment: There was some similar about struct read-only fields, in some cases when you try to modify them a temporary variable is created and modified, but the original remains. Maybe your case is the same.

Comment: Hopefully it goes without saying, but: if you violate the rules, bad things can happen. Be glad you got a sensible result, instead of a catastrophe.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a bad design, that's for sure, but that was just a little research. Back then I just wanted to know how to change readonly field via reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a JIT-compiler's optimization. JIT inlines static readonly fields.

Let me explain that.

Let's start with simple facts:

> Static constructors are only called once in a process for each type.

So, static readonly field can only be initialized once, unlike instance readonly fields:
instance constructor can be called multiple times (in order to create new instances of a class), so there can be multiple, different values when it comes to instance readonly fields. You can't inline some instance's readonly field in a method, because there might be other instances that method is working with.

> When you access any type's or its instance's data or functions or whatever else, the static constructor of that type has already been called.

That means, static constructors are always called first when accessing a type. So, static readonly field must have already been initialized!

> JIT-Compiler perfectly knows what i'm talking about above.

So, why not decide to inline that static readonly field in a method that's using it?

See, if a method is using that static readonly field, then it is accessing that type. If it is accessing that type, then static constructor of that type has already been called, and static readonly field has already been initialized. Static constructor will never be called again and static readonly field will have the same value until you don't restart the app! Why not inline it in a method if we know that field will always have the same value?

Comment: Consts are even more aggressive.  They're inlined by the compiler.  Yes, this means it is insufficient to recompile an assembly with modified consts unless you also recompile any dependencies that reference them.

Answer (score 3):

Probably just a JIT optimization to prevent reading the variable multiple times.

You're changing a memory location you've declared as readonly, so shouldn't be surprised if readers cache the values.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I want to get more detailed and accurate answer on this question, e.g how exactly it all happens on low-level, because I'm learning .NET and that's why I wrote that code. It was designed only for learning purposes, but I didn't expect the value to be displayed as 10.

Comment: Ok.  I can tell you that tho optimization is not in the MSIL.

Comment: Or maybe it is only bug of the debugger showing wrong values?

Comment: Well yeah, i was checking IL (or MSIL) code for my C# code and i didn't see anything weird happening. Your opinion is that it's JIT compiler that sees that it is a readonly variable and creates 2 same Console.WriteLine instructions?

Comment: Check my new answer, I did a huge research (reverse engineered jit compiler and found out what the hell was happening) <-- just kidding :D, i just guessed while speaking with some guys like me who are interested in those deep things